# game.manifest not working on ipad

Tags: html, ipad

I have an iPad app game I tweaked from a tutorial. I have `html manifest="game.manifest"`. 
The game.manifest on server says

```
GAME MANIFEST

CACHE:
Bubble.html
js/Wrong.js
js/Particles.js
js/Bubble.js
sounds/burst.aif
image/Front.png
image/Back.jpg
```

server MIME is set up with .htaccess

When I save it to the home screen it won't open in airplane mode. It says "cannot be opened because you are not connected to the internet".

The game is at www.kobernik.com/bubblepop/balloon.html

Why is it not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first line of your manifest has to be `CACHE MANIFEST` and not any arbitrary title.

Comment: Thanks, I did have Cache Manifest on a couple copies, changed it back. Many thanks to Kristian also, he helped me with setting up developer tools to see the errors in my code. Worked through line by line to fix the errors and now it works.